# Grow div container from the bottom without altering the baseline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div that when the mouse is over it, a child div is expanded from the bottom, revealing all of its hidden contents.
However, the div seems to shrink a bit from the bottom, making the elements below it rise slightly.

[**Here is an fiddle showing exactly what's going on.**](https://jsfiddle.net/YonicStudios/qw9207on/10/)

```css
body {
  color:white;
}

.game-thumbnail {
    background-color: rgba(23, 30, 26, 0.95);
    margin-top:-15%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    padding:0.5em 1em;
    transition: margin 0.333s ease-out, padding 0.333s ease-out;
}

.game-entry {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:66vw;
    max-width:500px;
}

.game-entry img {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.game-entry:hover .game-thumbnail {
        margin-top:-30%;
        padding-bottom:15%;
        bottom:0;
}
.game-entry:hover .moreinfo {
        opacity:1;
        transition:opacity ease-out;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.moreinfo {
    opacity:0;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    background-color:#171e1a;
    width:25%;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid my-0 px-5 py-1">
    <div class="container-fluid p-2 d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-auto p-2">
                <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0 game-entry">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cxLk553.png">
                    <div class="container-fluid game-thumbnail">
                        <h4>My Dog's Tale</h4>
                        <p>Follow the adventures of My Dog</p>
                        <div class="moreinfo">More info...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="my-4" style="color:black;">This should not go up</h1>
```

I was thinking of just repositioning the text upwards, making the div bigger at the top, but the background stays behind the image.

Although I'm looking for a CSS3-only solution, jQuery solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you use margin to adjust the positioning of an element, it will impact the DOM flow of the rest of the page. This is why it is impacting the positioning of the element below.

I would advise using `transform` to accomplish an animation like this. For example, `transform: translateY(-30%);`. This will move the element "up" without impacting DOM flow.

See updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qw9207on/15/).